# How to change a Dialog's background overlay color

Tags: android, styles

I want to change the overlay color of a dialog. The first which comes as transparent gray.

I tried:

```
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@color/customColor</item>
<item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@color/customColor</item>
```

They did not work. When I tried:

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/customColor</item>
```

The content background is changing.

Answer (score 0):

I found a one rule solution!

```java
d.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.menubackground);
```

It works for me with a normal dialog.
But I dont know if it works on an `AlertDialog`.